# Creating a post that contains a list of other posts like a table of contents

Tags: order

Is it possible for a post to contain a list of other posts, with a custom ordering like a table of contents?

Similiar to the above but is it possible to create a category with a custom ordering of the posts?

Comment: Yes it is possible to have generate a list of posts and put it just about anywhere. Why do you want it in another post?  What "custom ordering" are you wanting?  You can easily order any output of post/page links by things like title, author, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Wordpress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts):

> The most appropriate use for `get_posts` is to create an array of posts based on a set of parameters. It retrieves a list of recent posts or posts matching this criteria.